# Signed a lazy minting voucher .How can i list the nft in opensea

Tags: blockchain, ethereumjs, eip712

**This is my voucher code :**

```
async function main() {
  const [admin, minter, relayer] = await ethers.getSigners();
  console.log(`Sign authorization:`);
  
  const registry    = (await attach('ERC721LazyMintWith712', process.env.ADDRESS)).connect(admin);
  const { chainId } = await ethers.provider.getNetwork();
  const tokenId     = process.env.TOKENID || 1;
  const account     = process.env.ACCOUNT || '0x8c8e240C723F5F850c6fdfD04a1B08598DaF6B53';
  const uri = "ipfs://bafybeibnsoufr2renqzsh347nrx54wcubt5lgkeivez63xvivplfwhtpym/metadata.json";


  const voucher = { tokenId, uri, account }
       console.log(voucher);
       const domain = {
       name: 'Name',
       version: '1',
       verifyingContract: registry.address,
       chainId: '4'
      }

     const types = {
      NFTVoucher: [
        {name: "tokenId", type: "uint256"},
        {name: "uri", type: "string"},  
        {name: "account", type: "address"},
      ]
    }
 
  
  const signature   = await admin._signTypedData(domain,types,voucher);
  console.log({ registry: registry.address, tokenId, account,uri, signature });
}

main()
  .then(() => process.exit(0))
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });
```

**This is the output result :**

```
{
  registry: '0x083f6a7a8393a5A2660aFAb869E5eCb50dD46b26',
  tokenId: '1',
  account: '0x8c8e240C723F5F850c6fdfD04a1B08598DaF6B53',
  uri: 'ipfs://bafybeibnsoufr2renqzsh347nrx54wcubt5lgkeivez63xvivplfwhtpym/metadata.json',
  signature: '0x8338df852a63c6e72b16033434b20614c466f1d0204b219fe523f35790bc837f19b7d52a333a3805aa29906933a3b1081333792225c3527a875042855e4647e01b'
}
```

**How can i list the nft in opensea using this signature?**